# PHP Mailer message not coming through correctly

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer

Hope there is someone out there that can help me. I am playing around with PHP mailer to send out my daily production reports for my machines (Just to make my life easier obviously) but every mail i send only returns "1" in the message body. Dont know where i went wrong if anyone can assist.

Here is my PHPMailer code:

```
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP(true);                                     
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com:465';  
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
$mail->Username = 'XXXXXXX';              
$mail->Password = 'XXXXXXX';                   
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';       
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->From = 'XXXXXXX';
$mail->FromName = 'Automated Reporting';
$mail->addAddress('XXXXXXX@XXXXXXX');    
$mail->addReplyTo('XXXXXXX@XXXXXXX');
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  
$mail->Subject = 'Daily Production Report ';
$mail->Body    = include_once('./scripts/Daily.php');
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

When i run this script it returns the values that i need it to (daily.php) and displays correctly on my screen and i also get a message that the mail has been sent. But the mail i am receiving just has "1" in the message body, nothing else.

Contents of DAILY.php

```
<?php

$mydate=getdate(date("U"));

//OPEN Table for the production report
echo "<h1> ".$mydate['weekday'] , " " , $mydate['month'] , " " , $mydate['mday'], " " , $mydate['year']." :: " , " 311 Warehouse" , "</h1>";
echo "<table width=100% border=1>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th width=124>Shift / Line</th>";
echo "<th width=124>Handset</th>";
    echo "<th width=124>Handset EOL</th>";
    echo "<th width=124>Wallet 1</th>";
    echo "<th width=124>Wallet 2</th>";
    echo "<th width=124>Wholesale</th>";
    echo "<th width=124>Wholesale EOL</th>";
    echo "<th width=124>Blister</th>";
    echo "<th width=124>Blister EOL</th>";
    echo "</tr>";


    $SCADA = mysqli_connect("XXXXXXX","XXXXXXX","XXXXXXX","XXXXXXX");

//MYSQL Connection Error
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    $values = array();

 //311 Working Queries
    echo "<tr>";

    echo "<th width=124>DayShift : </th>";

    //Handset Kitting Totals
        $query = "select count(id) from HandsetKit_T where createdDate between '2014-06-23 05:00' and '2014-06-23 14:00';";
        $result = $SCADA->query($query) or die($SCADA->error.__LINE__);
        if($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<td width=124>", stripslashes($row['count(id)']);
            }
        }
        else {
            echo 'NO RESULTS';
        }

    //Handset Kitting EOL Totals
        $query = "SELECT CONCAT 
    (
    (SELECT COUNT(p.id) as 'PalletS'
        FROM Pallet_T p, PalletNotify_T pn 
        WHERE p.id = pn.`palletID` 
        AND p.createdDate BETWEEN '2014-06-23 05:00' and '2014-06-23 14:00'
        AND pn.esbStatus = '3'
        AND p.mtnAssetID NOT LIKE '11' AND p.mtnAssetID NOT LIKE '12'
    ) , ' / ' ,
    (SELECT COUNT(p.id) as 'PalletF'
        FROM Pallet_T p, PalletNotify_T pn 
        WHERE p.id = pn.`palletID` 
        AND p.createdDate BETWEEN '2014-06-23 05:00' and '2014-06-23 14:00'
        AND pn.esbStatus = '4'
        AND p.mtnAssetID NOT LIKE '11' AND p.mtnAssetID NOT LIKE '12'
    )) AS 'HK EOL'";
        $result = $SCADA->query($query) or die($SCADA->error.__LINE__);
        if($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<td width=124>", stripslashes($row['HK EOL']);
            }
        }
        else {
            echo 'NO RESULTS';
        }

    //Wallet One Totals 
    $query = "select count(id) 
    from Kit_T where mtnAssetID = '3' and createdDate between '2014-06-23 05:00' and '2014-06-23 14:00';";
    $result = $SCADA->query($query) or die($SCADA->error.__LINE__);
    if($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<td width=124>", stripslashes($row['count(id)']);
        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'NO RESULTS';
    }

    //Wallet Two Totals
    $query = "select count(id) 
    from Kit_T where mtnAssetID = '10' and createdDate between '2014-06-23 05:00' and '2014-06-23 14:00';";
    $result = $SCADA->query($query) or die($SCADA->error.__LINE__);
    if($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<td width=124>", stripslashes($row['count(id)']);
        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'NO RESULTS';
    }


    //Wholesale Bricking Totals
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(b.id) as totals
    FROM Brick_T b, BrickNotify_T bn
    WHERE b.id = bn.brickID
    AND createdDate BETWEEN '2014-06-23 05:00' and '2014-06-23 14:00'
    AND bn.esbStatus = '3'";
    $result = $SCADA->query($query) or die($SCADA->error.__LINE__);

    if($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<td width=62>", stripslashes($row['totals']);
        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'NO RESULTS';
    }


    //Wholesale EOL Totals
        $query = "SELECT CONCAT 
    (
    (SELECT COUNT(p.id) as 'PalletS'
        FROM Pallet_T p, PalletNotify_T pn 
        WHERE p.id = pn.`palletID` 
        AND p.createdDate BETWEEN '2014-06-23 05:00' and '2014-06-23 14:00'
        AND pn.esbStatus = '3'
        AND p.mtnAssetID = '12'
    ) , ' / ' ,
    (SELECT COUNT(p.id) as 'PalletF'
        FROM Pallet_T p, PalletNotify_T pn 
        WHERE p.id = pn.`palletID` 
        AND p.createdDate BETWEEN '2014-06-23 05:00' and '2014-06-23 14:00'
        AND pn.esbStatus = '4'
        AND p.mtnAssetID = '12'
    )) AS 'WEOL'";
        $result = $SCADA->query($query) or die($SCADA->error.__LINE__);
        if($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<td width=124>", stripslashes($row['WEOL']);
            }
        }
        else {
            echo 'NO RESULTS';
        }


    //Blister Totatls
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(bb.id) as totals
    FROM BlisterBrick_T bb, BlisterBrickNotify_T bbn
    WHERE bb.id = bbn.blisterBrickID
    AND createdDate BETWEEN '2014-06-23 05:00' and '2014-06-23 14:00'
    AND bbn.esbStatus = '3'";
    $result = $SCADA->query($query) or die($SCADA->error.__LINE__);

    if($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<td width=62>", stripslashes($row['totals']);
        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'NO RESULTS';
    }

    //Blister EOL Totals
    $query = "SELECT CONCAT 
    (
    (SELECT COUNT(p.id) as 'PalletS'
        FROM Pallet_T p, PalletNotify_T pn 
        WHERE p.id = pn.`palletID` 
        AND p.createdDate BETWEEN '2014-06-23 05:00' and '2014-06-23 14:00'
        AND pn.esbStatus = '3'
        AND p.mtnAssetID = '11'
    ) , ' / ' ,
    (SELECT COUNT(p.id) as 'PalletF'
        FROM Pallet_T p, PalletNotify_T pn 
        WHERE p.id = pn.`palletID` 
        AND p.createdDate BETWEEN '2014-06-23 05:00' and '2014-06-23 14:00'
        AND pn.esbStatus = '4'
        AND p.mtnAssetID = '11'
    )) AS 'WEOL'";
        $result = $SCADA->query($query) or die($SCADA->error.__LINE__);
        if($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<td width=124>", stripslashes($row['WEOL']);
            }
        }
        else {
            echo 'NO RESULTS';
        }

    echo "</tr>";

echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($SCADA);


?>
```

UPDATE: I have resolved the issue by changing the code in my mailer function using an output buffer to store the results in a variable which i include in my mailbody (see revised code below):

```
ob_start();
include('./scripts/Daily.php');
$mailbody = ob_get_contents();
ob_clean();
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP(true);                                     
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com:465';  
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
    $mail->Username = 'XXXXXXX';              
    $mail->Password = 'XXXXXXX';                   
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';       
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->From = 'XXXXXXX';
    $mail->FromName = 'Automated Reporting';
    $mail->addAddress('XXXXXXX@XXXXXXX');    
    $mail->addReplyTo('XXXXXXX@XXXXXXX');
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  
    $mail->Subject = 'Daily Production Report ';
    $mail->Body    = $mailbody;
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
$mail->Body    = include_once('./scripts/Daily.php');
```

is incorrect. `include` generally DOESN'T "return" anything, other than a true/false to signify if the file was actually loaded or not.

You probably want something more like:

```
ob_start();
include_once(...);
$mail->Body = ob_end_clean();
```

This'll capture the output of the included file, which you can then stuff into PHPMailer.

Comment: Interesting solution! I'm also wondering if the OP wants the contents of the script to be evaluated before being sent out...

Comment: Hi guys thanks for the prompt reply, i actually have no intention of evaluating the contents of the mail before sending it out. i want to basically automate my reporting. The Daily.php script connects to my MySQL database and pulls the figures for the previous day's production.

Comment: well, that's fine. but you're treating include() as if it was a regular function. it's not. it's job is to load a specified file and EXECUTE it.

Comment: @MarcB how will i go about getting the data returned from daily.php into the body of the email? i have updated the original post with the contents of this file

Comment: Thanks guys i have managed to solve the issue using @MarcB suggestion. just added a variable $mailbody = ob_get_contents(); which puts the contents into a variable which i call on later in my $mail->Body tag.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, `include` returns `1` as a normal success return value, but you can get [a return value from an include statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php#example-158) by having a `return` statement in the file you include, so if you make your Daily.php return an appropriate string, your original code will work just fine. Using output buffering is quite inefficient.

BTW include is not a function, so you don't need parentheses around the path:

```
$mail->Body    = include './scripts/Daily.php';
```

Also you don't want `include_once` - if you had included it previously, it would return a boolean true instead of the expected return value.